# Send JS script from NodeJS server to client a execute it, the client cannot see JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to send JS script from NodeJS to a client and execute it in such a way that the client does not see the JS script. Can I do it this way?

1. generate some JS script on NodeJS server
2. send JS script to client
3. execute JS script on client-side

**But with a little detail the client cannot see the JS script.**

Comment: That isn't possible. If its in the browser you can see its contents. You shouldn't ever need to 'hide' javascript on the client anyway, so if you find yourself needing to do that you probably have a pretty big design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use eval(response.data) to run your response from the nodejs server. Even if client cannot see the script  in the contents .. it will be on the network calls tab.